# Play Store says "can't install this app try again, and if it still doesn't work, see common ways to fix it" after downloading is 100% complete

Tags: android, build, google-play, version, google-play-console

Play Store says "can't install this app try again, and if it still doesn't work, see common ways to fix it".
I have published UPDATE of my different android apps on play store and it got successfully live as usual. But the thing is that on my Google Play Console all apps' new install were ZERO from past 2,3 days.
Manifest AND Build Gradle: App are attached.
I WANT TO MENTION THAT THE APPS ARE BEING DOWNLOADED FOR 100%, then the below dialogue is displayed.

[Message Shown on Each Apps Installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOUOo.jpg)

Below is manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com...">


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" />

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/ime_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    tools:replace="android:icon,android:label">


    <activity
        android:name="com...Main"
        android:screenOrientation="unspecified"
        android:label="@string/ime_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".PrefActivity"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"




 android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|
 screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="@string/ads_application_id"/>

</application>

</manifest>
```

**Build Gradle : App**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 'android-R'

buildToolsVersion '29.0.2'

defaultConfig {

    applicationId '...'

    minSdkVersion 16

    targetSdkVersion 29

    versionCode 4

    versionName '4.43'


}
lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}

buildTypes {

    release {

        minifyEnabled true

        shrinkResources true

        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

productFlavors {

}
}
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
implementation project(':lib')
implementation project(':library')
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.0.1'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
}
```

Comment: is this message from playstore?, try stop your playstore and open again

Comment: this message is from play store. It's not problem on only my play store. Downloads on new releases are zero for each app I updated. It means no user is able to install these apps on their devices.

Comment: what is the solution for this? Some users can't download my app.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have answers for you, but would like to help you debug this issue. If you have a device that reproduces the problem, try connecting it to your ADB and reading through the error logs what is happening when you get this message. In my case it was something like:

> Submitter: commit error message INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE:
> Package signatures do not match previously
> installed version; ignoring! Task Failed: tid:1000000026,
> statusCode:6004
> com.google.android.finsky.installerv2.InstallerException: Status: 6004

This made me conclude that there was nothing wrong with the update itself. I was just trying to update from the version that Google Play did not sign to the one signed by Google Play. Not to mention it was a false alarm as my users were not dealing with this issue at all.

Hope you guys find your error message and get to fix your problems!